# Convert xpath queries to Query Builder in aem

Tags: xpath

I am trying to convert XPath queries to predicates that I can use with the QueryBuilder. For example, I have an XPath as follows:

```
xpath = /jcr:root/content/voda//element(*, cq:PageContent)
[(jcr:contains(@jcr:title,'*') or jcr:contains(.,'*')) and (@cq:template='/apps/cc/templates/people') and (@role!='Other') and @cq:template!='/apps/cc/templates/internalredirect']
/(rep:excerpt(.))
```

I want to use QueryBuilder instead of XPath.

Also, please suggest some reference material that would help me in general to change other XPath queries to a QueryBuilder format.